# Laravel temporary variable for multiple file input (images) upload from popup modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, upload, bootstrap-modal

My project is to create a multi-file upload, where user uploads it from a popup modal, but not directly inserted to the database. So uploaded files(images) would be saved on some kind of variable and the details stored on the dynamic table which could be reviewed or deleted before the user upload those files to the database. How could I do this?

So far I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647024/getting-moving-cloning-fileimage-input-from-popup-modal-to-hidden-input-inside) and asked but got no response. My friend told me to use some sort of API AJAX or something instead of form, which I have no knowledge of yet. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: your logic is okay. why not create temp_table to store all the files before after decision, move the files to the permanent table or delete from the temp_table as simple as it is.

Comment: I have think of that, but what if there are more than one user that want to upload simultaneously? Wouldn't it be some sort of chaos in the temp_table?

Comment: nope! because each user would have a unique id in the database

Comment: Ahh, i will try that, thanks! But that means i would have to delete some undeleted junk somehow (like when user close the tab without clicking delete or cancel the upload form, with something called onunload i believe? is that really practical?

Comment: something like that. just try and see what you're going to come up with. And don't forget to click on the pyramid-like icon besides the comments if you find the comment useful to the post.

Comment: Yeah, i dont think i could upvote / give rep yet since my own reputation is low (i think the priviliage of upvoting is like when i have 15 rep myself).
And thanks again.